# SSL handshake problem when WWW version of website is accessed

Tags: nginx

I have a problem with my Nginx configuration

I want to make redirect from www to non-www version of my website
http://example.com -> https://example.com
https://www.example.com -> https://example.com

When I try to access https://www.example.com I receive this message in my browser
[image]

When I make openssl request to debug the certificate I receive a handshake problem (40)

```
openssl s_client -connect www.example.com:443 -prexit
```

Output

```
CONNECTED(00000006)
4536557228:error:14004410:SSL routines:CONNECT_CR_SRVR_HELLO:sslv3 alert handshake failure:/AppleInternal/BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/libressl/libressl-56.60.2/libressl-2.8/ssl/ssl_pkt.c:1200:SSL alert number 40
4536557228:error:140040E5:SSL routines:CONNECT_CR_SRVR_HELLO:ssl handshake failure:/AppleInternal/BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/libressl/libressl-56.60.2/libressl-2.8/ssl/ssl_pkt.c:585:
---
no peer certificate available
---
No client certificate CA names sent
---
SSL handshake has read 7 bytes and written 0 bytes
---
New, (NONE), Cipher is (NONE)
Secure Renegotiation IS NOT supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
No ALPN negotiated
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1.2
    Cipher    : 0000
    Session-ID: 
    Session-ID-ctx: 
    Master-Key: 
    Start Time: 1620807828
    Timeout   : 7200 (sec)
    Verify return code: 0 (ok)
---
```

This is the configuration file for my server blocks

```
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name example.com;
        # proxy_cache_valid 301 60m; # cache permanent redirect for 1 hour
        return 301 https://example.com$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name www.example.com;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

    return 301 https://example.com$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    
    server_name example.com;
    
    root /var/www/html;

    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    location /data-centres-report {
        # Redirect knight frank report from blog to app
             return 301 https://example.com$request_uri;
    }

    location / {
        proxy_redirect http:// https://;
        #try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
                #include fastcgi_params;
                #include fastcgi.conf;
                include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
                fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
                fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
                fastcgi_buffers 16 16k;
                fastcgi_buffer_size 32k;
                #fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        }


        ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
        include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
        ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}
```

Comment: Perhaps asking in Serverfault.  SO is for programming questions.

Comment: Have you checked that `example.com` and `www.example.com` point to the same IP address? And is it the IP address of this server or some reverse proxy living in front of it?